# So i'm trying to get my axios response in an array and I don't know how to do it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So i'm trying to get my axios response from a spring boot page into a vuejs array And i don't know why but apperently i can't use split here. I'm pretty new to vue.js so please go easy on me.

Vue.js code:

```
// JavaScript source code

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            urls: [],
            url: ""
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:91/all/URL")
            .then(response => (this.url = response.data, this.urls = this.url.split(",")))
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul v-for="url in urls">
            <li> {{ url }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

console throws following error:

```
Script.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.urlfound.split is not a function
    at Script.js:14
```

Comment: What's ``response.data`` output?

Comment: Also what errors are thrown in browser dev tools console (if any)?

Comment: The error indicates `this.urlfound` is not an array. What is the value of `this.urlfound`? Where is that code in your question? (Is that just a renaming of `this.url`?)

Answer (score 1):

There is conflict between variable names, in template you have url from v-for and also in data the same url is defined.